# Django OAuth with Xero SDK can't access session for oauth2_token_getter and oauth2_token_saver as no request object can be passed

Tags: python, django, xero-api, requests-oauthlib

I am using Django with requests_oauthlib to access the Xero API using the xero-python SDK.

[Xero Starter Demo](https://Xero%20Starter%20Demo)

[requests-oauthlib](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

I am trying to use request.session to store the oauth token information. This works well on the initial call and callback, but in subsequent views when I want to load the correct token from the request.session I am hitting a problem.

The Xero ApiClient (xero_python.api_client) wants me to configure two functions it can call to get and save the token in the future (oauth2_token_getter, oauth2_token_saver) (decorators are used in the demo). Those functions are called by the Xero API and take no parameters. I can create the functions no problem, and they get called correctly, but once inside the functions I have no request object so I can't access request.session to get or save the token to the session.

The Xero demonstration projects use Flask which imports a root level session object (from flask import session) which can be accessed in any function, so this works fine for Flask. What is the correct way to solve this problem in Django?

I have tried creating a SessionStore object but it was empty despite me knowing the data is in the request.session

I have also tried importing requests.session but this doesn't seem to be what I am looking for as I can't get it to read/write any data.

Some Code:

Saving the token in the callback works as I have a request.session:

```
def xero_callback(request):
    ...
    request.session["oauth_token"] = token
    ...
```

The Xero ApiClient is configured with the methods for getting and saving:

```
api_client = ApiClient(
    Configuration(
        debug=True,
        oauth2_token=OAuth2Token(client_id=config.XERO_CLIENT_ID, client_secret=config.XERO_CLIENT_SECRET),
    ),
    pool_threads=1,
    oauth2_token_getter=oauth2_token_getter,
    oauth2_token_saver=oauth2_token_saver)
```

This doesn't work as I have no request object and can't pass one in:

```
def oauth2_token_getter():
    return request.session.get("token")    #! FAIL, I don't have access to request here
```

The error is thrown after calling identity_api.get_connections() as it tries to get the token using oauth2_token_getter and fails

```
def xero_tenants(request):
    identity_api = IdentityApi(api_client)
    accounting_api = AccountingApi(api_client)

    available_tenants = []
    for connection in identity_api.get_connections():
        ...
```

Any help appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to store the token in the django cache? (`django.core.cache import cache`) Then instead of specifying `oauth2_token_getter=oauth2_token_getter` in the ApiClient constructor you can do:

```
@api_client.oauth2_token_getter
def obtain_xero_oauth2_token():
    return cache.get('token')
```

and something similar for the setter/saver.